# How to automatically transfer Google Doc (Google Drive) form data to Google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to automate the process of transferring data that a form user submits (on a Google Doc Form), to a separate document (a Google Doc Document) that has empty fields for this data.

For example the person's name or DOB entered on the form would automatically get transferred to an area of the document where I would like it to appear, amongst other pre-existing information in the Document.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to link the form to a spreadsheet on Google Forms. Just click "Choose response destination" to set it.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of the Forms Service in May 2013, you have a couple of options to accomplish this.

1. A script bound to your Form can modify a Document. A form-bound script will receive a *Form Submit Event* with a [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) object. Your script would use [Document Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) to open and modify a document with content of the FormResponse.
2. A script bound to a spreadsheet that is receiving Form input can modify a Document. A spreadsheet-bound script will receive a *Spreadsheet Form Submit Event*. Again, use Document Services to update your document.

References:

- [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)
- [Extending Google Docs / Replacing Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#replacing_text) shows how to replace placeholders in a target document.